# Is it ok for a cast iron skillet to have small visible pores on their surface?

Tags: cast-iron, cookware

I just got my first cast iron skillet, it's brand new pre-seasoned. While I know cast iron is generally porous, I was surprised to see actual visible pores in there. Is it normal for cast iron cookware to have these sort of pores?

[image: I'm pointing at one, but you will see few others above]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pan was cast in sand, and it looks like that one was, it's not unusual at all. As long as you have a good seasoning on it, I think it should be fine.